# How to fix SSL "page can't be displayed" error with VS2013 and a basic ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, windows-8, iis-express, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to do something that feels like it should be straightforward. I have VS2013 on Win8 and I'm just experimenting with a vanilla MVC ASP.NET project to gain some web experience. This works fine in IE10 until I try to enable SSL.

To do this, I select the project, go to the Properties window, and change the "SSL Enabled" property to "True". Then I copy the value of "SSL URL" to the "Project Url" edit box under Project/Properties/Web.

After these steps, when I try to launch the website I get a "page can't be displayed error".

Looking in the system log, I see two relevant events:

1. Source: Schannel, ID: 36870, Description: "A fatal error occurred when attempting to access the SSL server credential private key. The error code returned from the cryptographic module is 0x8009030D. The internal error state is 10001."
2. Source: HttpEvent, ID: 15021, Description: "An error occurred while using SSL configuration for endpoint 0.0.0.0:44300.  The error status code is contained within the returned data."

What am I missing to be able to enable SSL? I am trying to follow the tutorial here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on#author-info

Thanks.

Comment: I'd really appreciate any ideas people may have on how to fix this issue. I observe it on both my dev machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix was to uninstall and reinstall IIS 8.0 Express. This fixed the issue on both machines.

Comment: For me this is only a temporary fix.  After reinstall I can get it working again but soon after for reasons unknown to me it reverts back to the Page Can't be displayed error.  I'll still looking for permanent fix

Comment: I'm currently struggling on the exact same issue and I believe the problem is related to the certificate for localhost that is either missing or incorrect (in my case the one cert I had didn't have a private key, which is not ok for SSL, I deleted it and I'm trying to create a new one now).

Comment: Using a small command line tool call SelfSSL7 was the easiest way, my problem is fixed now.

Comment: Worked for me with IIS10.

Answer (score 0):

you can check your IIS https bindings, it should attached to a certificate, I had the same problem, my certificate was removed from IIS binding and I got the same error as above.